# Where/how do I view the Chang'e 2 lunar map?

Tags: the-moon, mapping, chang-e

"In February 2012, the Chinese government released a complete lunar map constructed from Chang'e 2's data, claiming that it was the highest-resolution map of the entire Moon yet recorded."

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_2#Lunar_mission

Where/how do I view this map?

Comment: I keep coming up with links to here: 159.226.88.30:8080/CE2release/cesMain.jsp 

But this link seems to be dead now.  Still trying to find a source besides just the overall images.

Comment: I've seen comments saying that the file size is 800GB. Has anyone got a copy you can make available as a torrent?

Comment: I don't know of anyone who does, but I'll keep looking.  Would like the data myself...

Comment: @M.A.H. Virtual Moon Atlas: http://ap-i.net/avl/en/download seems to have a Chang'e 2 texture down to 60m per pixel, so the authors must have the raw data/images. Also there are papers being published with Change'e 2 data like this: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1179/1752270614Y.0000000111 so the probe's data is clearly available to Chinese universities. The resolution of the published images is supposed to be as good as 1.3m, according to the Wikipedia link in the question.

Comment: @M.A.H. Found this journal article: http://english.gyig.cas.cn/pu/papers_CJG/201402/P020140226618307463779.pdf about the data including screenshots of the interface of the data release system but I still can't figure out how to access it. The URL given in the article doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find the map but I can offer a video! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGmwrC-gArM&t=5s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the link: http://moon.bao.ac.cn/searchOrder_dataSearch.search

You may need to create an account.

Scientific Data -> Search -> find your data and download.

The website is extremely slow, and not user friendly at all.

The search page is so slow, may take 30-180 seconds to load.

The download link looks like:

http://moon.bao.ac.cn/cedownload/CCD/IMAGE/DOM/CE2_GRAS_DOM_07m_S030_70S112E_A.tif

More details on file naming:

[image]

You can change the language to English on the main page: http://moon.bao.ac.cn/index_en.jsp

Comment: I haven't seen a site that slow since the 90s, it took about five minutes to load. Could you give us some background? Why is it so slow? Who exactly is publishing it? The Chinese government's "Lunar Exploration Program"? Why was it initially available and then not for a couple of years? Also, I've found the tables you posted, but I'm using Google translate. How did you get an English version? Just trying to download some of the historical landing spots, have you managed to do so?

Comment: @nmit026 why it's slow: I just had another try from Canada, the loading time of search page and result page seems acceptable (<10s) at this time.

Comment: @nmit026 many of China's gov websites suck because of outsourcing. A company  with relationship win the bid at 100k, outsourcing to a small company with 10K, then assign the task to an unpaid intern student (rumors, but you'll get the point). this website is even worse than a student project. I'm a web developer, by running a test, https://www.webpagetest.org/performance_optimization.php?test=190113_2G_9729e25108b6563eb53591f824d28ba5    this website has no cache, no compression, and the background image is > 1Mb.

Comment: @nmit026 for download speed, the server seems hosed on "CHINA SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY NETWORK",  it's non-commercial and has limited BGP peers [ https://bgp.he.net/AS7497#_peers ] most peers are research institutions.  Downloading from residential ISP (Comcast/Bell/AT&T) would be slow

Answer (score 0):

It's incredibly slow, but the easiest thing to do seems to be to go to the home page, select English, and work from there. You can also create an account, not sure what benefit that has though. I'll update this answer as I go, it's taking a very long time to load anything.

Here's the home page:

http://moon.bao.ac.cn/index_en.jsp

Here is an interactive 3D map of the moon:

http://moon.bao.ac.cn/moonGisMap.search